# api for new and stable versions of Ubuntu

Tags: html5, javascript

I am trying to build an automatic Ubuntu widget for my [website](http://www.eurobytes.nl/), that displays the latest version and the next to be released version and the to be LTS versions.

Right now at every new Ubuntu release I have to get the data manually. New name, new logo, new version numbering.

Is there an Ubuntu website api which I can get the data for new, stable, supported releases. Maybe even the new logo? Set it and forgot it is what I have in mind. Which of course some configuration options. Api would make it allot easier.

Thinking about using [`http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/`](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/) or [`http://releases.ubuntu.com/`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) But It would mean allot of work parsing the code.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DeveloperNetwork may be what your looking for

> Launchpad entry: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-api-website
>
> Define collections of API versions as a distro release (Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 12.10, etc)

Not 100% sure if this info will help you. This question might be best asked in a developer community.